# Accessing specific elements of a struct

Tags: matlab, properties, struct, return

Say that I have the structure `r`, with the property `a`. If we want to access the property `a`, I think we can do the following:

`r.a`

Here, this will return all the values of `a`.

How can I return `a` that has only specific values? Say for instance I want the values were `a=55`

Thanks.

Comment: are you going to ask a question about every single line of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
[r.a] == 55
```

or else `r([r.a] == 55)` if you want the structs themselves

e.g.:

```
r(1).a = 1;
r(2).a = 2;
r(3).a = 55;
r(4).a = 3;
r(5).a = 55;

[r.a] == 55

ans =

   0   0   1   0   1
```